# Load testing basic authentication with parameters with Gatling - Scala

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a problem when trying to use the basicAuth method with parameter retrived from a csv files.

Here is my code:

class spiSimulation extends Simulation {

```
val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://spi.test.com")
    .inferHtmlResources()

val headers_0 = Map(
    "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control" -> "no-cache",
    "Pragma" -> "no-cache",
    "Proxy-Connection" -> "keep-alive")

val users = csv("users.csv")

val scn = scenario("LosspiSimulation_request")
.feed(users)
    .exec(
        http("request")
            .get("/SPI/Basic").headers(headers_0)
            .basicAuth("${login}", "${password}")
            .headers(headers_0).check(
            header("Set-Cookie").saveAs("Cookie")))
    .exec(
        http("validate")
            .get("/SPI-back/Validation?cookie=${Cookie}")
            .headers(headers_0))

setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(10) over (2 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

}

When I use only one user and hard code my login and password it works. But with param login and password, I have two errors when running the Gatling script, one is "No attribute named Cookie" is defined and "No attribute named login is defined".

Here is a sample of my csv file:

```
login, password

test01, password01

test02, password02
```

I would be pleased if you can find a solution.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How does you csv file look like? In particular does it have a header line?

Comment: Yes the first line is login in the first column and password in the second

Comment: Could you post a sample? Just to make sure it looks ok, you know like whitespaces, separator characters, etc..

Comment: I have done it with excel and save it as csv file it it ok ?

Comment: the first line I enter login password and then there is 50 lines with real login and password

Comment: I don't know what your excel does by default, it would be easier if you just update the post with a sample. Maybe it's nothing, but it would be good to exclude it. You can of course remove usernames and passwords, but leave whitespaces and everything else intact.

Comment: I have edited my question with a sample of my cvs file. I have done it with a text editor, still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try without whitespaces in the CSV file :)

The [Feeders](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/session/feeder.html) documentation of Gatling explicitly states that they honor only [The RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). They do not automatically trim whitespaces.

Should be:

```
login,password
test01,password01
test02,password02
```

Comment: There is no space in my csv file, I don't understand what you are talking about ?`

Comment: Well, in your pasted CSV sample you have "username, password". Note the space after the comma. Is it a copy-paste error, or is it actually in your file?

Comment: Ah ok, now it seems to be ok with login and password, but I still have an error with Cookie.

Comment: Here is the two errors: header(Set-Cookie).find(0).exists, found nothing           and No attribute named 'Cookie' is defined

Comment: It seems that the variable $login does not take the value in the csv file...it stays $login

Comment: Nah, I don't think so (but enable debug logging to be sure). Are you sure you removed the white spaces no only for the header line, but also FOR ALL THE CSV LINES? Otherwise, you're sending "test01 " instead of "test01".

Comment: What do you mean by enable logging ?

Comment: I found the error I have a backslash in all username that do not appear after applying the csv function, do you have a solution to include this backslash or to make it visible ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is ok I append the backslash after :)

Answer (score -1):

Last line 
setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(10) over (2 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
You declare 10 user and program must have 10 user in csv file.